# How to search for documents which meet meet a criterion of "is between"?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents similar to

```
{
   "name": "A",
   "start": 5,
   "end": 10
},
{
   "name": "B",
   "start": 1,
   "end": 10
},
{
   "name": "C",
   "start": 20,
   "end": 30
}
```

I also have a value `X` (say, 7). I need to look for documents such that `start < X < end`. In the example above, this would yield two documents (with `name` equal to `A` and `B`).

I do not know how to to formulate the search query: the [`range` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) which initially seemed to be the right one actually looks for documents which meet a criterion "greater than" / "smaller than" passed in the query - which is the opposite of what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following two `range` queries would work

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                 {"range": {"start": {"lt": 7}}},
                 {"range": {"end": {"gt": 7}}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I had luck with this :) Sorry for the delay - I am reviewing all my questions, notably for elasticsearch and specifically from you to make sure everything is closed and clean :) Thanks again, as usual.